# Wordpress Define Variable Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, constants

I'm attempting to create a plugin for a site in Wordpress for both practice and execution. In this plugin will be a variety of files. I want to define the plugin directory as a constant so I use:

```
define('CUSTOM_EDITING__URL', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__));
```

When I include:

```
//FOLDERS
define('WIDGETS', CUSTOM_EDITING__URL . 'widgets/');
require_once(WIDGETS . 'widgets.php');
```

I'm able to get to the file `widgets.php`, but when I call inside of the file:

```
echo CUSTOM_EDITING__URL;
```

I get CUSTOM_EDITING__URL. I want http://www.example.com/widgets/widget.php

Can someone explain what I'm missing?

**EDIT: More information about the problem at hand.**

Right now I have figured out that widgets.php is not accepting the defined variables. For example... the calling file is able to create a widget using the format of:

```
class Foo_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    // Content
}
```

But the widgets.php file cannot resolve to find WP_Widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is my answer. I don't have any actual good documentation to explain it. I copied some of the elements from the Akismet plugin to successfully get it to work the way I needed it to.

```
define( 'CUSTOM_EDITING__URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );
define( 'CUSTOM_EDITING__DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );


require_once( CUSTOM_EDITING__DIR . 'class.custom-editing-widget.php' );
require_once( CUSTOM_EDITING__DIR . 'class.custom-editing.php');



register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'CustomEditing', 'plugin_activation' ) );
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'CustomEditing', 'plugin_deactivation' ) );

add_action( 'init', array( 'CustomEditing', 'init' ) );
```

In the file `class.custom-editing.php` I create the class with these base parameters:

```
class CustomEditing {

    private static $initiated = false;

    public function __construct(){
    }

    public static function init() {
        if ( ! self::$initiated ) {
            self::init_hooks();
        }
    }

    private static function init_hooks() {
        self::$initiated = true;
    }
}
```

This solves my any base errors that are created by the activation hooks I believe. If someone can explain the parts to this in better terms that would be appreciated, but I don't fully understand why this worked and what I had didn't.

Answer (score 0):

The constant method might help:

```
echo constant("CUSTOM_EDITING__URL");
```

Comment: `Warning: constant() [function.constant]: Couldn't find constant CUSTOM_EDITING__URL` which means it isn't being defined in the file. Which is kinda what I'm seeing... I'm not sure why nothing is defined within the file since the file that is calling it includes all necessary file calls.

Comment: That explains why `echo CUSTOM_EDITING__URL;` echoes the literal string. Is this code inside widgets.php? You may need to add a `require` statement in widgets.php for the file which declared `CUSTOM_EDITING__URL`.

Comment: i don't know how to explain perfectly, but that didn't work. Throws errors for the wordpress functions being used because it basically isn't connected to the wordpress files.. that's my best guess... It should be able to go **BASE FILE > SUB FOLDER > FILE > functions** but right now it just goes **BASE FILE** and won't go any deeper